# MySQL trigger to update SQL Server table

Tags: mysql, sql-server, triggers, linked-server

Is it possible to update a table in SQL Server using a trigger in MySQL. The scenario is like this.

When a table is updated in MySQL, a corresponding update is to be done in SQL Server for the purpose of syncing certain fields. I understand that the reverse is possible using a linked server in SQL Server.

Answer (score 3):

You can write a [UDF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-function-udf.html) function that would update data in the SQL Server. Then call this UDF from the trigger.

Comment: Is it possible for the MySQL UDF to update the SQL Server table.

Comment: UDF allows to use C++ code. I think you will find many examples in the internet (e.g. c++ how to connect to sql server).

Answer (score 0):

Here's some information which may be of help regarding linking SQL Server and MySQL

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?60,123221,123221

I'm afraid I've no personal experience in the matter as I thankfully have MySQL servers across the board, however had a scan through the links in the above and at least one of them should be able to assist.