# Data synchronization between MySQL to MS SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have configured two servers: one MySQL and one MS SQL server.

Application will run on Linux server with MySQL database as data storage.

When a new row is added to specific table in MySQL I need to push that row into specific table in MS SQL server.

I know that on MSSQL can be configured Linked Server targeting MySQL server via MySQL ODBC Driver.

But how to force synchronization from MySQL? Can I somehow use trigger in combination with something to do my job?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29820937/execute-shell-script-command-from-mysql-trigger-stored-procedure may help you, even if it's a bit hack'ish...

Comment: got this, may look closer : [mysql-trigger-to-update-sql-server-table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414697/mysql-trigger-to-update-sql-server-table) && [update-sql-server-from-mysql](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39598/update-sql-server-from-mysql)